# How to locate the element using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, selenide

```
<input class="chkbx-selection ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" value="test" id="isAgreeChkBox" ng-model="$root.isAgreement">
```

Please help me find what is the xpath/css selector here? I need to locate this using locators in selenide

Comment: What element...? Edit the question please!

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.Id("isAgreeChkBox"));`

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.chkbx-selection.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid#isAgreeChkBox[value='test']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='chkbx-selection ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid' and @id='isAgreeChkBox'][@value='test']"))).click();
  ```